Localization of locally compact commutative ring
If $A$ is a locally compact (Hausdorff) commutative ring and $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$, is there any natural topology we can put on $A S^{-1}$ such that it also becomes a locally compact topological ring? The quotient topology with respect to the map \begin{align}
&A \times S \to AS^{-1} \newline
&(a, s) \mapsto as^{-1}
\end{align}
makes it a topological ring, but I don't know if it has to be locally compact, even if we assume that $S$ is locally compact itself.
